# Azure Notification Hub access through Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, azure, cordova-plugins, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to use azure notification hub to register an ionic application for push notifications. I already have the entire backend setup with Azure, and I really enjoy the convenience of having all the tools in one place. However, I am having trouble finding a javascript plugin to work with. The only thing I found was this REST API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223264.aspx . This I don't mind using, however I came across https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub . This doesn't seem to be working. I have started writing my own library based on the documents MS has provided. Is this the only way for Azure Notification Hub usage on an web app. It seems MS website has tuts for everything else, but HTML5 apps as far as Notification Hub goes.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/

...My question is has anyone else encountered this issue and what  are alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=azure

and here:

http://plugreg.com/search?q=azure

Maybe you find there a solution.

Comment: Thank you, I decided I would use Ioni.io... Since it was time sensitive.